# Photographer service or photography service

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

I was talking to a friend about his wedding. I run a company and give assignments to photographers. I asked him if I could offer him my photography services (one of my photographers). What would have been more appropriate?
 "My photography services"  or "my photographer services"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you run the company, offering your photography services is ok.  But for someone who isn't aware of your role, it will sound  like  you, yourself, will be taking the pictures.

Strictly speaking, it is either your company,  or your photographers who provide photography services. So to be clear, you could say "my photographer's services," or "one of my photographer's services."

My photographer services would be wrong.